# Parsing XML XPath - for loop to accessing all elements instead of only elements for the particular tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file that contains information about Playlists on itunes. I have successfully managed to parse info about the playlists name and id, but I am not able to get the songs in the playlists as the for loop goes through all the songs in every playlist and then displays them all. I would like it to be different for each playlist.

```
        NodeList tList = (NodeList) x.evaluate("/plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int j = 0; j < tList.getLength(); ++j) {
            Element track = (Element) tList.item(j);

            Double trackId = (Double) x.evaluate("key[.='Track ID']/following-sibling::integer[1]", track,
                    XPathConstants.NUMBER);
            tracks.add(trackId);
            p.setTracks(tracks);

        }
        Playlist play = new Playlist(name, persistentID, playlistId, tracks);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
```

The output:

```
Playlist [name=Music, persistentId=29E12A03204E072C, playlistId=2687.0, tracks=[1234.0, 1282.0, 1694.0, 1558.0, 1802.0, 1280.0, 1278.0, 1656.0, 1298.0, 1334.0, 1294.0, 398.0, 400.0, 402.0, 404.0, 406.0, 408.0, 412.0, 414.0, 416.0, 418.0, 422.0, 424.0, 426.0, 430.0...]
Playlist [name=Purchased, persistentId=29E12A03204E072C, playlistId=2687.0, tracks=[1234.0, 1282.0, 1694.0, 1558.0, 1802.0, 1280.0, 1278.0, 1656.0, 1298.0, 1334.0, 1294.0, 398.0, 400.0, 402.0, 404.0, 406.0, 408.0, 412.0, 414.0, 416.0, 418.0, 422.0, 424.0, 426.0, 430.0....]
```

I would like the track id's for each song to be relative to it's particular playlist but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Could anyone help?

Comment: the first `<dict>` tag is never closed. should it be closed before the second playlist is displayed or should it surround the whole thing?

Comment: Yes that  is closed in the file. The file is 30000 lines long, so when I was posting I accidentally left out the </dict> tag. I have edited it now.

Comment: As already said, change `NodeList tList = (NodeList) x.evaluate("/plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);` to `NodeList tList = (NodeList) x.evaluate("array/dict", dict, XPathConstants.NODESET);`, to evaluate relative to the earlier selected `dict` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ArrayList<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<Double>();` into the first loop and use a relative XPath expression:

```
    NodeList tList = (NodeList) x.evaluate("array/dict", dict, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    ArrayList<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int j = 0; j < tList.getLength(); ++j) {
        Element track = (Element) tList.item(j);
```